# Display exception message through javascript alert in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to show exception message through javascript alert box.

Here is the sample code.

```
public static void HandleException(Page page, Exception ex)
{
    string message = ex.Message.ToString();
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page, page.GetType(), "", "alert('"+message+"');", true);

}
```

It runs if i give literal values for the string variable. 
e.g.

```
string message = "Hello World";
```

But it fails if I give message = ex.Message;

Any Idea?

Comment: *"But it fails if I give message = ex.Message;"* Fails ***how***?

Comment: I mean the alert box does not show up. It shows up only if message variable has literal string

Comment: I bet there's an error message somewhere. Check out the JavaScript console of the browser.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to encode it, for example using [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) because if the message contains some escape characters like `'` or `"` this will definitely break your javascript:

```
var message = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ex.Message.ToString());
var script = string.Format("alert({0});", message);
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page, page.GetType(), "", script, true);
```

Comment: I needed to modify a library function that returned the first line since the scripts were already being built on all the pages. I found trimming the quotes helpful since the Serialize adds enclosing quotes: new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ex.Message.ToString()).Trim('"');

Answer (score 3):

```
try    
{    
    //do some thing    
}    
catch (Exception ex)
{    
    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('" + 
        Server.HtmlEncode(ex.Message) + "')</script>");    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does your `ex.Message` have any ' characters in it? They may need escaping.