# Bootstrap Modal Popup to display dynamic content from server side code

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a web forms project using a combination of C#, Bootstrap and Jquery. I have an empty modal on the master page that I call if I want to display any kind of message on the screen to the user.

I pass the text I want to display to a Jquery function (also on the master page) which alters the text on the modal.

Passing simple text messages such as "Hello World" work fine, but if I want to display something more complicated such as html code or output text from an error exception then the modal just doesn't appear. No error messages, just nothing.

Any ideas/comments would be greatly appreciated.

**Modal Code on master page**

```
<div id="modalAlert" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;</button>
                <h1 class="modal-title">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAlertHeader" runat="server" Text="Heading"></asp:Label>
                </h1>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="modalAlertBody">

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Function on master page**

```
function ShowAlert(heading,message) {
$('#modalAlert').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false, show: true });
    $('#lblAlertHeader').text(heading);
    $('#modalAlertBody').html(message);
}
```

**Server-side code on child page**

```
string alertHeading = "Alert Heading";
string alertMessage = "Alert Message";
string function = string.Format("ShowAlert('{0}','{1}');", alertHeading, alertMessage);

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", function, true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not referencing your label object correctly in the client side code.  On the rendered HTML your label's ID will be something along the lines of `Body_lblAlertHeader`

You can use `$('#<%=lblAlertHeader.ClientID%>').text(heading);` to get the correct ID at runtime.

Use F12 (development tools) in your browser. They all have it these days but Chrome has probably the best (imo). Make sure you're not getting any console errors, your JQuery/JavaScript as it is will break if you have an apostrophe in the message or header string. When JavaScript breaks it typically bombs out all preceding JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have updated the header label as suggested. Having looked at Dev tools I get an "unterminated string constant" error. I've looked at the values of alertHeading and alertMessage in VS immediate window and there are no apostrophes, only "function" has apostrophes in it to show that the values entered are strings.

Comment: Got it working now thank. Your post and the following helped me get to the solution in the end, needed to encode it using JavaScriptSerializer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450235/display-exception-message-through-javascript-alert-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Inside your showAlert function first open the modal as

```
$("#modelAlert").modal({ 
      background: 'static',
      keyboard: false,
      show: true});
```

After it opens, use shown.bs.modal event which fires after modal opens.That means it will fill the dynamic content after the modal opens

```
 $( '#modalAlert').on
      ('shown.bs.modal' , function() {
     // put here your dynamic           messages.
    });
```